# How to implement ReactJS with AdonisJS using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, adonis.js

i made a simple CRUD system using AdonisJS (with the help of the views "Edge template system") and MySql for the back-end and i want to use ReactJS for the front-end but i don't know how to implement `create-react-app` so i can call the pages i created on the server to react page
here's the folders structure that i have now https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfo8s.png

Comment: I think your question is a bit too general. Do you have a particular problem with, for example following a create-react-app guide/tutorial? Generally the project structure should merge quite nicely with yours.

Comment: @DonSteep ...I just don't know how to use create-react-app with adonisJS, all the tutorials about ReactJS&AdonisJS i found are using AdonisJs as an API only that they consume in the front-end using reactjs, but for my case i created admin side using the views in Adonisjs, now i want to create the client side using create-react-app and i don't know how, should i just install in the same directory of adonisjs ''create-react-app''  or what ?

Comment: Ok, so I think your problem is a matter of routing, not so much the directory structure - as long as your create-react-app build doesn't overwrite your static files generated by adonis. In production environment the configuration is actually easier than in development when your backend is able to serve all static files including your react page.

Comment: @DonSteep I'm having a hard time articulating my thoughts (since English is my third language & i'm a newbie  ), but i guess you got it right, i don't know how to make react serve my adonis pages